# How do I place a hat over hair?

Tags: modeling

I have created a character in Makehuman and imported it into Blender 3.0. I would like to add a hat to the character's head with Blender. How do I setup the hair & hat so the hair does not protrude through the hat?

Another thing, is it possible to edit the hair and clothes in Blender? When in edit mode there is no mesh for the hair.

[image]

Cheers Ivan

Comment: just a hint: do only ask ONE question. If you ask more than one...your question might get closed quickly....(these are the rules here, i didn't make them, some of then are ridiculous...but you will see...)

Comment: If your hair is still hair, you can edit it in Particle Edit mode. When you want it to be converted to mesh you go into the Modifiers panel and press Convert

Comment: Thanks again moonboots. As you suggested, I converted the hair to a mesh. Then added a cube over the hat down to the rim and applied a boolean to the hair to get the difference between the cube. Hair all gone. For some reason, the hat could not be used with the boolean modifier in Cycles - although the hair was gone, the holes from the hair remained in the hat. The hat and boolean modifier worked fine with Eevee.